# Create hive table in pyspark hive context

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, hivecontext

I have 3 tables in abc hive database with Avro format. I want to create the another database(def) and create those 3 tables in hivecontext pyspark through data frames. 
More info: in abc database 3 tables all columns will b string but while I create it to def dAtabase those tables should be created with its respective columns.
Eg., abc database
Table1 —>name : string,id:string,dob:string

But in I want to create def database
Table 1 __>name: varchar,I’d:int, dob: timestamp

Comment: what did you try ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is __better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing__ what you expect to happen.